# What language do Sense8 speak within their cluster?

Tags: languages, sense8

It was not clear to me while watching. Do the characters speak English with each other, or does each one simply speaks his/her own language and the others understand?

It is confusing also to understand since their environment speak English.  Is it just to make the show easier to watch, or is it as if each character speaks his/her own language and we are able to understand it as 'our' language?

I remember there was an episode where Naomi was asked how many languages can she speak. She answered 7, so I believe she counted the mother tongues of her cluster (English, Spanish, German, Icelandic, Hindu, Swahili, Korean).  But in a later episode, Riley tells Will that she can speak French, and therefore he can too; shouldn't Naomi count this language as well?

Comment: The last part, about the number of different languages spoken/understood by the cluster, should probably be asked separately.  The first 2 paragraphs fit together as aspects of a single question, but the last one seems incidental to the question in the title.

Answer (score 2):

It's my understanding that when Sensates speak mind-to-mind via telepathy, there is not a specific dialect.

Scenes that support that include when Bug talks with Nomi and Lito in the movie theater (Bug speaks in Spanish to be understood by Lito), as well as when all the gang plus their significant others are in the one house in Europe, preparing for the final battle with Whispers/Lila in the season finale episodes.

Answer (score -2):

Nomi may have but Riley also knows French and Dutch (at least), as she spoke Dutch in S2E1 when buying a bag of stuff and both Riley and Will speak French when talking to that one club owner

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question wasn't about what languages any specific character can speak it's what language (if any) does the cluster use to communicate internally.

Comment: yep, was just pitching in because I thought the fact the cluster knows  like 10+ languages AT LEAST was pretty cool. also by the club Owner I meant Georges (I think?)